# What is the rationale for using scoring methods after logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, prediction

I generally come across scoring in logistic modeling (also other methods like discriminant analysis, etc.).

I want to know what is the use of scoring of individuals after running a logistic regression (or any other method). Can anybody suggest me some literature on the use of scoring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about literature, but the basic idea is to use a model to rate new subjects. For example, if you ran a logistic regression to try to model whether a person would vote Democratic or Republican, you could score new people to try to predict how they would vote.

Comment: So, are you saying that I used the beta values of logistic regression to predict the "new" data points, whether he is Democrat or Republican?

Comment: Not the beta values alone, but the predicted values for each case.  If you look into texts on logistic regression you'll find formulae for converting the equation for the logit into an equation for the probability that any given case would be a "1" on the dependent variable.

Comment: Thanks Rolando! The post is around for quite sometime. I didn't expect somebody will reply it now. But your comment make things pretty clear.